# Applying stats.percentileofscore to every row by column

Tags: python, pandas

df=

```
1
5
34
5
67
8
98
```

I need a new column with the percentile score for each element with respect to the column.
The final answer should look like this. I want the output of the stats.percentileofscore() function to be inputted into the pcntle_rank column. I thought about using apply somehow but how do I pass the required function parameters to percentileofscore?

df =

```
value    pcntle_rank
1        stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][1])
5        stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][2]) 
34       stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][3]) 
5        stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][4]) 
67       stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][5])
8        stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][6])
98       stats.percentileofscore(df['value'], df['value'][7])
```

This is my attempt. I would like to do this without a loop. The real data has 50 columns and 4000 rows. I will need to do this for every column and row.

```
  for i in range(df.shape[0]):
      df['pcntle_rank'][i] = stats.percentileofscore(df.loc[:,['value']],df['value'][i])
```

My loop gives results but I want to do it without a for loop.

Comment: If each column needs to be ranked separately, I think you must loop over the columns.

Answer (score 4):

### [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html)

with `pct=True`, this is the equivalent of stats.percentileofscore with the default `kind='rank'`

```
df[0].rank(pct=True)*100
#0     14.285714
#1     35.714286
#2     71.428571
#3     35.714286
#4     85.714286
#5     57.142857
#6    100.000000
#Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

---

```
from scipy import stats

for idx, val in df[0].iteritems():
    print(f'{val}: {stats.percentileofscore(df[0], score=val)}')

#1 : 14.285714285714286
#5 : 35.714285714285715
#34 : 71.42857142857143
#5 : 35.714285714285715
#67 : 85.71428571428571
#8 : 57.142857142857146
#98 : 100.0
```